# C# Unity - identify which method is affecting a GameObject

Tags: c#, function, unity-game-engine, function-call

I have this code here:

```
public void Move(Transform from, Transform to, float overTime)
{
    StartCoroutine(_Move(from, to, overTime));
}
IEnumerator _Move(Transform from, Transform to, float overTime)
{
    Vector2 original = from.position;
    float timer = 0.0f;
    while (timer < overTime)
    {
        float step = Vector2.Distance(original, to.position) * (Time.deltaTime / overTime);
        from.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(from.position, to.position, step);
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

which is quite simple. All it does is that it moves a `GameObject` to a destination over time. I plan to use it for UI animation purposes. 
However, things get interesting when I want to vary the use of this. 
For example, I hover my mouse over a button, which starts moving. While it still moves, I may hover over it again, in that case I want it to restart, so it stops the **function affecting the exact same button and restarts another one**. I just have no clue how to identify which call of the same function affects my given component. Or shall I add this script to every object so it can affect only that one?

Comment: You might want to have a look at the http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Might not be a bad idea. 
For now though, is my question clear? Or shall I edit?

Comment: Your question is clear and appropriate on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> While it still moves, I may hover over it again, in that case I want
>   it to restart, so it stops the function affecting the exact same
>   button and restarts another one. I just have no clue how to identify
>   which call of the same function affects my given component. Or shall I
>   add this script to every object so it can affect only that one?

One solution is to attach a script that contains the coroutine function to **each** GameObjects. If you don't want to do this then there is another way to do this.

First of all, simply storing `IEnumerator` is not enough to actually do this. You need a way to identify the GameObject running in the last coroutine.

**1**.Get a value that can be used to identify the Object. In this case, the instance ID with `GetInstanceID()` should be fine.

**2**.Make a simple `struct` that will hold the old coroutine information.

**3**.Finally, Make a Dictionary that will hold both the instance ID(key) and that struct from **#2** as value.

With these three things, you can start a coroutine, add it to the `Dictionary`. When the coroutine is finished, remove the the `instance ID` from the `Dictionary`.

The code below will make one coroutine control many objects without placing the coroutine function in its own script. The big difference is that when new cororutine is called on the-same function, it stops the old one on that object **only** then creates a new one and start it.

This is what I use. It is very well commented so that you will know what's going on.

```
Dictionary<int, MoveInfo> movingObject = new Dictionary<int, MoveInfo>();

public void Move(Transform from, Transform to, float overTime)
{
    MoveInfo moveInfo;

    //Check if the Object exist in the Dictionay
    if (movingObject.TryGetValue(from.GetInstanceID(), out moveInfo))
    {
        //This Object exist and therefore, the coroutine function is already running. Stop it

        //Remove it from the Dictionary
        movingObject.Remove(from.GetInstanceID());

        //Stop the old coroutine
        StopCoroutine(moveInfo.currentCoroutine);
    }

    //Create a new coroutine
    moveInfo = createMoveInfoInstance(from);

    //Add it to the dictionary 
    movingObject.Add(from.GetInstanceID(), moveInfo);

    //Get instance of the new coroutine we are about to start
    moveInfo.currentCoroutine = _Move(moveInfo, from, to, overTime);

    //Modify the dictionary because the Add function does not update the currentCoroutine reference
    movingObject[from.GetInstanceID()] = moveInfo;

    //Start the coroutine
    StartCoroutine(moveInfo.currentCoroutine);
}

MoveInfo createMoveInfoInstance(Transform from)
{
    MoveInfo moveInfo = new MoveInfo();
    moveInfo.instanceID = from.GetInstanceID();
    return moveInfo;
}

IEnumerator _Move(MoveInfo moveInfo, Transform from, Transform to, float overTime)
{
    Vector2 original = from.position;
    float timer = 0.0f;

    Debug.Log("New Coroutine Started");
    while (timer < overTime)
    {
        float step = Vector2.Distance(original, to.position) * (Time.deltaTime / overTime);
        from.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(from.position, to.position, step);
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
        yield return null;
    }

    //Remove it from the Dictionary if it exist
    if (movingObject.ContainsKey(from.GetInstanceID()))
    {
        movingObject.Remove(from.GetInstanceID());
    }
}

public struct MoveInfo
{
    public IEnumerator currentCoroutine;
    public int instanceID;

    public MoveInfo(IEnumerator currentCoroutine, int instanceID)
    {
        this.currentCoroutine = currentCoroutine;
        this.instanceID = instanceID;
    }
}
```

Comment: Advanced stuff, maybe a bit too advanced to me but this is how I learn :) 
I try to implement it but in case of fail, I still can compile my functions to a .dll file and use them in a script that is put on each of my UI elements, where the UI element and the script has a 1:1 relationship (effected by only that, effects only that).

Comment: It's not really advance. If you copy that and replace it with the code in your question, it should compile and work fine. *The goal of this solution is that it makes it so that you don't have to attach the Move code to very UI*. You just pass in the transform and the new potion and it will take care of that.

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot I'd do differently here. For one thing if your Ui object is already affected by a coroutine you don't want another coroutine to start acting on it as well, just the new coroutine. To avoid this declare a coroutine variable:

```
IEnumerator myCoRoutine
```

When you first mouse over start the coroutine like this:

```
myCoRoutine = _Move(from, to, overTime);
Start Coroutine(_Move());
```

But, you want to check if a coroutine isn't already running, and stop it if it is, then start a new one, right? So, do this:

```
if(myCoRoutine !=null) StopCoroutine(mtCoRoutine);
myCoRoutine = _Move(from, to, overTime);
Start Coroutine(_Move());
```

You'll likely want to start your coroutines using [OnPointerEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventTrigger.OnPointerEnter.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help, useful indeed. 
Now, I might effect say an image with 2 of these as I have scale, rotate, lerpAlpha and so on written, so e.g. a button slightly grows and fades in. But in general, yes I want only _one_ scale, only one move etc to effect it. 
I google about that `OnPointerEnter` though.

Comment: Note: At the bottom, we should `StartCoroutine(myCoRoutine)` instead of `Start Coroutine(_Move())` ? Or do I understand something incorrectly?

Comment: If you want multiple things to happen to an object it's best to combine them in one coroutine, so perhaps your _Move function will do scale and rotation and position, or you'll have several methods to do it. Either way do it all in one coroutine. Regarding StartCouroutine yes you start the coroutine you declared as a variable, see here https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html

Comment: Another thing, I might want to call this `Move()` to move 2 buttons at once. Can I do that with your solution? Or should I just put one script to one UI element so it is affected by solely that script and that script can effect only that element?